# firebase auth asking for authorization code during installation

Tags: angular, firebase

am trying to install firebase authentication and it's asking for an authorization code in the cli. no matter how I check I don't see any authorization code (I have web api keys etc provided in the firebaseConfig) am I missing something obvious? here is what my steps look like in the cli:

```
ng add @angular/fire
Skipping installation: Package already installed
UPDATE package.json (1493 bytes)
? What features would you like to setup? Authentication
Using firebase-tools version 10.2.0
? Allow Firebase to collect CLI usage and error reporting information? No
? Enter authorization code:
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I had the same problem. I solved it by following those steps :

1/ First, you have to connect your firebase account
`> firebase login`

2/ Next, check if the connection is alright (you need to create your project on firebase in a first place to see it in the result)
`> firebase projects:list`

3/ Then, you need to initialize firebase
`> firebase init`

4/ And now you can add the following command
`> ng add @angular/fire`

Comment: thanks. of the features listed after the command firebase init. which one contains the authentication service?

Comment: Authentification service feature is listed in the `ng add @angular/fire` command, at the question : 'What features would you like to setup ?'

Comment: I've figured it out. silly me

Comment: Thank you, Works fine for me. 
But i did not need to do the `firebase init` command. That step can be avoided

Answer (score 4):

It's recommended to use `ng add @angular/fire`, because it simplifies the setup process and ensures that everything is properly configured.

Another possibility is to skip the `ng add @angular/fire` command and run `npm install @angular/fire firebase` instead. Then you will need to configure the application's module file and set up the Firebase configuration in your environments files manually.

For example if you want to apply Firestore Database execute

```
<your/project/path>$ npm install @angular/fire firebase
<your/project/path>$ ng generate environments
```

then modify your `app.module.ts`:

```
...
import { provideFirebaseApp, initializeApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { getFirestore, provideFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    ...
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore())
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

environment.ts and environment.evelopment.ts:

```
export const environment = {
    firebase: {
        apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        authDomain: "xxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
        projectId: "xxxxxx",
        storageBucket: "xxxx.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxx",
        appId: "1:xxxxxxxx:web:xxxxxxxxx"
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If you validate your account of Firebase and related projects in the validation mail they sent, this message should not appear.
If still there, try this command:

> firebase login:ci

and authorize access to your project in the window that will popup. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to solve this problem, and also wanted to add a comment to the correct one, but couldn't, so here is one extra step I wanted to add:-

1/ First, you have to connect your firebase account > firebase login

2/ Next, check if the connection is alright (you need to create your project on firebase in a first place to see it in the result) > firebase projects:list

3/ Then, you need to initialize firebase > firebase init

4/ And now you can add the following command > ng add @angular/fire

5/(added) ---> Then do > npm install firebase

Answer (score 0):

1. Install firebase-tools `npm install -g firebase-tools`.
2. Configure your firebase project on the web
3. Do `firebase login` in the console
4. And `ng add @angular/fire` should work